# Where can I find accurate documentation about lithium-ion batteries?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I would like to design a lithium-ion battery analyzer, but I feel that I don't know much about these batteries. There are many concepts like SoC, battery impedance, battery health status, etc., that I don't fully understand, and I'm not sure how to measure them. Could you share detailed information about lithium-ion batteries with me?

Answer (score 4):

For a general primer, I recommend [Batteries in a Portable World: A Handbook on Rechargeable Batteries for Non-Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0968211844).

For a detailed dive-in, please forgive me for a shameless plug for my book: [Lithium-Ion Batteries and Applications](https://us.artechhouse.com/cw_Search.aspx?k=Lithium-Ion+Batteries+and+Applications).

Comment: @SamGibson: is this allowed?

Comment: Quite the pair of volumes. I like the brief but useful list of key non-English terms.

Comment: @DavideAndrea  Ah, a person who knows about L-ions. Is it the case that floating one indefinitely at 4.0 V is feasible, and less damaging than charging to 4.2 V then letting it drop to 4.1 V before recharging, accepting that a lower SoC will be acheived?

Comment: Less damaging, correct.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I don't see why linking to your own book when it's the requested answer would be not allowed. That would be counter-productive. Sure, it's not fine if you "slid" in this link without mentioning it's your book into a lot of more-or-less relevant answers, but you don't do that at all – you do your best to answer the question, and you clearly say, hey, this is my book.

Comment: @DavideAndrea - Hi , Re: "*is this allowed?*" a) FYI I didn't get a notification, despite you typing my username, as I hadn't made any comment before yours above. The Ajax (JS) code would not have autocompleted my username. The `@username` in a comment can only be used to notify *previous comment-writers on that post* (with a few extras like editors). Unfortunately it's ... [complicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019). I just noticed this when looking at questions for interest, not as a mod, so I'll do my best to reply.

Comment: (b) No problem with you mentioning your book as such - it's relevant, you disclose the connection [as required](/help/promotion), and you don't promote excessively. **But**... This is a link-only answer. Also, the question title & body are different - title invites possible link-only answers (could lead to question being closed), but body asks people to "*share detailed information about lithium-ion batteries*" which this answer doesn't do - there is no detailed information about batteries in the answer, just links. In that respect, the question is too broad, as it would take a book to answer.

Comment: See [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) which explains the problems with these types of questions & answers. The question's author explaining the problems is *Shog9* who was SE staff at the time, so it is official. The aim of SE is that answers should be self-contained & links should be for *supplementary info only* (i.e. not for an essential part of the answer). || My summary: Despite good intentions, it's a problematic situation - there's a too-broad question where the title invites links yet the body asks for detailed info, and a link-only answer :(

Comment: @SamGibson. Understood. Let me offer a possible solution: address each of OP's subjects (SoC, impedance, health) with a short definition and a link to more complete answers already offered within this stack exchange. Kindly let me know what you think of this suggestion, before I do anything else.